# How to automatically heartbeat a TF2 listen server?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, server-administration

I am running a listen server from time to time to play with friends, i get annoyed that in order for the server to be lsited on the internet i have to manually "heartbeat" and "map " in the console. Is there a way to somehow automate this? I already have a "listenserver.cfg" file set up, but adding the commands there does not work, is there a way to set up the game to run these commands once the server loads, as i tend to let it load in the background and run other errands meanwhile?

Comment: I think listen servers are assumed to be LAN servers.  Usually it's better to just run a Dedicated server.

Comment: yeah, but the option to make them internet servers is viable and i don't like the idea of a dedicated server, i'm just doing it randomly for a while to play with friends i wouldn't like to have extra needless software on my PC, plus extra load, plus extra setting-up etc.

Comment: Is the convar `sv_lan` set to 0? I think it gets set to 1 in `listenserver.cfg` by default.

Comment: @Suchipi, thank you for trying, but you totally missed the point - i am looking for a way to make my computer/game automatically update the map with the command "map <mapname>" i am NOT looking for the obvious answer to "how do i make my game appear on the internet?". How is that not clear?

Comment: I asked because sv_lan 1 servers don't heartbeat, that's all

Comment: @Suchipi, at this point i doubt "heartbeat" even does something at all (coz recently i tried using only "map <mapname>", sv_lan 0 ofc) and my server was on the internet

Comment: Changing map with "map whatever" will automatically heartbeat (when sv_lan is 0), so yes

Comment: @Suchipi, well this is certainly news to me and most sites about TF2 that i have read. And here i was, sitting, thinking we were in the 21st century and on the vast, infinite network of tremendous knowledge, called the Internet, there would be sufficient and detailed information on something that has not only been made by humans, completely capable of explaining how stuff works, but that has existed for more than 10 years.

Comment: *"on the vast infinite network.. called the Internet, there would be sufficient and detailed information on something...that has existed for more than 10 years"* - Yeah, you'd think that. Then again, I do programming for a living and like 80% of the time this **isn't** the case. :-P

Answer (score 1):

According to Valve's Developer notes on Heartbeat:

> This is, in short, a ping sent to the Steam servers when hosting your own server. It tells them your IP, amount of players, ping time, etc. This is usually not required, multiplayer or other, because it automatically runs the command every 30 seconds or so.
> <sub>- [TF2 Developer Wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Heartbeat)</sub>

So assuming you've done the other commands for setting up a listen server, i.e.

```
ip [your static ip address]
sv_lan 0
sv_pure 1
map [map name here]
```

You shouldn't need to run 'heartbeat' at all.

#### References

- [TF2 Developer Wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Heartbeat)
- [The Colloquial Coefficient: Hosting a Team Fortress 2 Listening Server](http://bryancao.tumblr.com/post/2180848795/hosting-a-team-fortress-2-listening-server)

Comment: Thanks, this question is so old I forgot to edit it. Now I actually need to automatically run the "map [map name here]" command, the others are set up fine.

Comment: @mathgenius you shouldn't move the goalposts, if you have a new question, ask it as a new question :-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that.

Well, the issue is the same, just the accompanying attribute is different. Do you think I should still ask a new question?

Comment: @mathgenius yes I believe so, despite being similar I think they're different enough to warrant being asked separately. You can rollback this question (and link to it in your new question for context if need be).